# Obtaining the number in CounterBox

Tags: front-end

Is there a way of obtaining the current number of a counterbox? Say for instance that in a new notebook you create 3 section cells. Then by evaluating the command:

```
CellPrint[Cell[TextData[CounterBox["Section"]]]]
```

You can see now many cells with the style `"Section"` you have created up to the point at which you evaluated the command.

[image]

Is there a way of obtaining the the number of "Sections" created without having to print a cell displaying a CounterBox? I would like to do something like:

```
GetCounterNumber["Section"]
```

and it should return the total number of Sections created. It should behave similarly for subsections and other cells that have counters.

Comment: see my edit. You should probably unaccept so people give it a shot

Answer (score 20):

Try

```
CurrentValue[{"CounterValue", "Section"}]
```

Comment: How did you find this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. The sequence took about 2-3 minutes:
1st minute) Have the impulse of giving a useless answer in a comment, of the lines of `TextRecognize[
 Rasterize[
  StyleBox[RowBox[{"Number ", CounterBox["Section"]}], 
   FontSize -> 40]]]`
2') Realizing that made no sense, didn't work, 0 became "O", etc.
3') Decided to try for real. Smelled CurrentValue had a chance. Went to the CurrentValue command list SE question. Ctrl+F, Counter. Found 2. Tried the most obvious, didn't work. Tried the second one. EUREKA
Unfortunately, no magic

Comment: To @MrWizard and all those of you who believed in me. In a recent answer to an old MrWizard's question, I realised that this code doesn't do what I implied. It gives you the TOTAL number of Section cells, not the number up to the point in question. This answer as well as that old MrWizard's one are still waiting for someone to, perhaps, understand how to get `CurrentValue[{"CounterValue", "Section"}]` to return something other than `1`. My sincerest apologies. Rojo... (someone call John Fultz)

Comment: Rojo, please add a note of this to the body of your answer; that edit will allow me to, sadly, remove my vote. :-/

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, c'est la vie

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I know you have v7, but I want my vote back ;D, works in v9

Comment: Some day you will get it. :->

Answer (score 11):

This now works in version 9:

```
CurrentValue[{"CounterValue", counterName}]
```

It determines the position from the cell which runs the evaluation.  So a <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> evaluation will look at the position of the Input cell, a button evaluation will look at the position of the button, a `Dynamic` will look at the position of the `Dynamic`, etc.